# Advice needed on AJAX URL

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm designing a website that's going to use XmlHttpRequest (AJAX) to communicate with the back-end.

I'm sending all such data requests to a single URL, rather than having separate URLs for different types of request. On the client and on the server, I'll pack and unpack the contents as necessary and determine who needs to respond using some kind of JSON envelope.

The purpose is to have one point of control for all communication, so that duplication is minimized and I can ensure that security is always properly performed.

**Is there a convention for the name of this URL?** (E.g. `/ajax`) It's hidden from the end-user, so not too important, but if there is a convention I'd like to follow it. I'm boring like that.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I don't think it's really suited for StackOverflow...

Comment: Thanks. I've altered the question slightly to make it less discursive.

Comment: Is it front controller pattern you are talking about? Some MVC implementations like ASP.NET MVC does pretty much what you want.

Comment: Yes, it's a variation of the Front Controller pattern, but on both sides of the connection, i.e. multiplexing and demultiplexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
My answer may not be satisfying enough, but perhaps better than the previous one...

Closest to that technology are probably webgl applications (3D) and games. Since they could use model loading at runtime and other stuff, but usually they don't  do this because they are not large enough yet. So if someone really want to find something, it is not bad place to start.

Once I did a small app, it was something like 3D model viewer. I thought of three ways of data transfer: web sockets, json data post/rec and binary data post/rec. 
I used json, because is more compatible then web socket and if it is bzipped/gzipped, then it has almoast same size as my binary file + it is human readable. You could also upload model asynchronously, so it was pretty close to your idea.

Back to your question, there are few implementation of it but not many. So I didn't see any standart. We use javascript so standardize anything here is a long trip. Anyway I don't suggest to you to use /ajax. Under ajax I see asynchronous request from client and xml data response from server. But this should be different concept, doesn't it?

Comment: I'm not talking about navigation and browser history etc. I'm only talking about data communication from a rich client-side application to a back-end server. I am planning to multiplex all the communication (probably using some kind of JSON envelope around the message content) down a single channel to a single URL (invisible to the end user). Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I've updated the question to be more clear about what I mean and what I'm really after.

Comment: So I updated my answer. I don't know much about that topic, but I have similar ideas. So let's share the few that I've found...

Comment: Thanks for your updated comment. I see what you're saying about `/ajax`. I think I will go with `/data` instead.